# How to poll current time after time.sleep function

Tags: python

I have a problem with a Python function, being a noob I am not really sure on how to proceed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
 import time
 import ephem
 import datetime

 now_l = now.time()
 print("Time at Start of script")
 print now_l
 sleep_time = 600
 time.sleep(sleep_time)
 now_l = now.time()
 print("Time at after Sleep")
 print now_l
```

When I run the script this is the result

```
Time at Start of script
16:38:59.210033
Sleeping for 600 seconds
Time at after Sleep
16:38:59.210033
```

I would need the current time after the sleep period to be queried in the same format. What do I do wrong ?

Comment: what is `now` in your code?

Comment: Looks like you wrote `now = datetime.now()` and forgot to post it.

Comment: Dan, this is true it is at another part of the script. Tried it out -- Solved !

Answer (score 1):

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

now_l = datetime.now().time()
print("Time at Start of script")
print now_l
sleep_time = 2
sleep(sleep_time)
now_l = datetime.now().time()
print("Time at after Sleep")
print now_l
```

Output of the abowe code is:

```
Time at Start of script
16:10:52.136008
Time at after Sleep
16:10:54.138556
```

Comment: I think this would be a good answer if you added an explanation that `datetime.now()` gets the current date and time when it's called, so you have to call that function again if you want the time later on.